# json response get data in div ajax

Tags: json, ajax

i get the json response  in different div
json response

```
 {"success":"you have not inserted","error":{"name":["The name field is required."],"detail":["The detail
 field is required."]}}
```

ajax code

```
function postdata(){

   var name=$('#name').val();
   var detail=$('#detail').val(); 
   var token=$('#_token').val();
  $('#post').val('Submiting...');
    $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'posts',
                    data: "name="+ name + "&detail="+ detail,
                    success: function(data){
                 }  });
```

}

get json respons message in this div

```
<div class="alert alert-info col-ssm-12" id="detail"></div>

    <div class="alert alert-info col-ssm-12" id="name"></div>
```

Comment: whats your problem you are facing?

Comment: this is SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: You should validate the JSON using any of the validators out  there http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: can you post the code inside your success function

Comment: we can't understand you, please provide full code..

Comment: i have this response from json  {"success":"you have not inserted","error":{"name":["The name field is required."],"detail":["The detail field is required."]}}   i display the success , name and detail in div how it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get Values by .text() or .html()

```
function postdata(){

   var name=$('#name').text();
   var detail=$('#detail').text(); 
   var token=$('#_token').val();
  $('#post').val('Submiting...');
    $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'posts',
                    data: "name="+ name + "&detail="+ detail,
                    success: function(data){
                 }  });
}
```

Comment: i have this response from json {"success":"you have not inserted","error":{"name":["The name field is required."],"detail":["The detail
 field is required."]}} and i dispay the success name and detail in  these div        <div class="alert alert-info col-ssm-12" id="success"></div>  <div class="alert alert-info col-ssm-12" id="name"></div>  <div class="alert alert-info col-ssm-12" id="detail"></div>    how it is possible

Comment: print your "name" and "detail" values on console before ajax call.